# What are the disadvantages of running multinode k3s over mainline kubernetes (k8s)?

Tags: kubernetes

K3s has [high availability multi-node support](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/architecture/#high-availability-k3s-server-with-an-external-db). This separates it from Minikube and the like, in that you can start out single-node and later make a multi-node k3s cluster.

Is there any reason to ever migrate from a multi-node k3s cluster to (a multi-node) full blown install of Kubernetes? What does Kubernetes proper have that the lightweight (but multi-node) k3s alternative does not have (especially now with k3s having "embedded etcd")?

Comment: K3S comes with a predefined stack, you might want to customize the stack (network, storage...) from the start.